# i want to parse the following JSON String. Please help

Tags: apex, json

I have two objects MDM_Object_Mapping__c(parent) and MDM_Field_Mapping_ims__c(chaild) are in MD relationship. My JSOn String is:

```
    public static List < JSON3Apex > parse(String json) {
        return (List < JSON3Apex > ) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List < JSON3Apex > .class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Editing your question after its been closed will put it into a queue for users to review it and  determine if it should be re-opened. Your edit removed nearly all of the content of your question, making it substantially worse. Your edit also failed to address any potential differences between your question and the duplicate. Next time, try to improve your questions after they've been closed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) utility which is a big work, but if your JSON is compatible with SObject - `MDM_Object_Mapping__c` (and if you are really lucky), try if [JSON.deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) works?

```
List<MDM_Object_Mapping__c> lstObjectMapping = (List<MDM_Object_Mapping__c>) 
    JSON.deserialize('your JSON String here', List<MDM_Object_Mapping__c>.class);
```